# automated email sending - variable in Htmlbody

Tags: google-apps-script

I'am very new in gas.
The scenario is this : 
Having a spreadsheet with the list of recipient and their names, I want to automate and customize the body of the email writing on the top "Dear {name}".
How can I pass the variable into the Htmlbody option?

Here is part of the code... Thanks in advance.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").getSheets()[0];
  var rng = ss.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow()-1, 8);
  var rngvls = rng.getValues();
  //
  for (var i = 0 ; i<rngvls.length; i++){
    var name= ss.getRange(i + 2, 5, 1, 1).getValue();
    GmailApp.sendEmail(dest, ogg, body,{name:nam, attachments: [fail.getAs(MimeType.PDF)], htmlBody : <html><h1>here is the header</h1> and here the name
</html>});
```

Answer (score 1):

The values are already in rngvls. Using the method getValue() in a loop isn't very good for performance.

You can add the name to a string containing the html using concatenation.

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i<rngvls.length; i++){

    var name = rnglvls[i+1][4];
    var html = "<html><h1>here is the header</h1>"+name+"html";

    GmailApp.sendEmail(dest, ogg, body,{name:nam, attachments: [fail.getAs(MimeType.PDF)], htmlBody : html});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions... The customer's request has become more demanding. Now he wants to send email with a google doc as template in the e-mail body.. I could not find out a solution, I am stuck in work with the right method in the Body class...

Comment: You can use the MailApp class TsunamiSteve mentions. Documentation can be found here, together with code for sending an attachment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app. Use MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS

Comment: Nothing... I can not do it. Every try have as Result a pdf as attachment. Is it right to get the doc content as blob? And then how could i push it on the body of my email? Sorry at this point I am stuck!

Comment: Use the export link. 

   var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id="+docid+"&exportFormat=html";
     var param = {
     method      : "get",
     headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}
     };
     var htmlBody = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,param).getContentText();
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can pass HTML formatting into the script by setting an HTML variable and then using that variable in the optional MailApp [arguments](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)).  You can also use other variables within the body using this approach.

It should be noted that the GmailApp class is more likely to require a re-authorization because it can access a user's inbox, so if all you're doing is sending mail the MailApp class is the recommended approach.

```
var1 = ...
var2 = ...
var3 = ...
var html = '<body>' +
  '<p>Message.</p>' +
  '<p><b>Variable 1: </b>' + var1 + '</p>' +
  '<p><b>Variable 2: </b>' + var2 + '</p>' +
  '<p><b>Variable 3: </b>' + var3 + '</p>' +
  '</body>';
MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, {htmlBody:html});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Drive service and get the export link.

```
var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id="+docid+"&exportFormat=html";
  var param = {
  method      : "get",
  headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " +     ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}
  };
  var htmlBody =     UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,param).getContentText();
 }
```

﻿

Comment: Thanks Riel, nice solution... but! It does not fill the email with formatting such as text-color, bold etc etc...

Comment: Actually, the mail does not show this. The HTML itself will show the proper styling, only when sent as email formatting is gone.

But I gave the wrong answer on the wrong question.


     for (var i = 0 ; i<rngvls.length; i++){
      var name= ss.getRange(i + 2, 5, 1, 1).getValue();
      var htmlBody = "<html><h1>here is the header</h1> and here the     name";
      htmlBody = htmlBody.replace("name",name)
      MailApp.sendEmail(dest, ogg, body,{name:nam, attachments: [fail.getAs(MimeType.PDF)], htmlBody : htmlBody})

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that you can use if you don't need to send too many emails messages (because it's rather slow), it uses a Google doc as a template with a few placeholders and creates a temporary copy of it that is converted to HTML and sent as a message body.

All the features available in Google docs are correctly translated in HTML, including images, fonts etc...

Some formatting are slightly modified (image alignment for example) but nothing to really worry about.

*If you are planning to send many messages you might need to create an automated process to send the messages in smaller bunches on a timer trigger but that would be out of subject here.*

### Code :

```
function customizeHTMLMessage() {
  var templateId = '1aZAgVbvZYD1JcoLqv8x-A5knHLrVNOfEyGh_O-06dgg';// the template doc with placeholders
  var docId = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId).makeCopy('temp').getId();
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);// the temp copy
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var items = ['#day#','#starter#','#main course#','#dessert#'];// the placeholders in this example
  var values = ['Monday','Smoked fish','Beef steak','ice cream'];
  for(var n = 0;n<items.length;n++){
    Logger.log(items[n]+' to replace with '+values[n]);// check in the log
    body.replaceText(items[n],values[n]);// update the temp doc
  }
  doc.saveAndClose();// save changes before conversion
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id="+docId+"&exportFormat=html";
  var param = {
  method      : "get",
  headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " +     ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}
  };
  var htmlBody =     UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,param).getContentText();
  var trashed = DriveApp.getFileById(docId).setTrashed(true);// delete temp copy
  MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),'test','html body',{htmlBody : htmlBody});// send to myself to test
}
```

note : this template doc is shared (view only) you can make a copy to test it.

---

Edit : screen capture in 2 different mail readers.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the result is still a loss of text-formatting...My work-around is to create a page in google-sites and script this:
var mysite = SitesApp.getSiteByUrl("https://sites.google.com/site/xxxxxxxx");
  var htmlBody= mysite.getChildByName("pagenamexxxxx").getHtmlContent();
MailApp.sendEmail("email",'test','html body',{htmlBody : htmlBody});

Comment: The email body is exactly what is in the doc (I added a couple of screen captures in my answer, one from Gmail and one from thunderbird). You will notice that the result depends also on how you read the mail. Most of the email client programs respect completely this format but, for example, the gmail web view does not. That said, I'm not sure one can send a complex  html message that will look identical in any circumstance. Do the results with SiteApp return constant results on any client ?

Comment: Serge thanks for you precious feedback. I am testina,  but actually the Result with siteapp is Acceptable and reliable. I ll keep you up to date. Thanks again